# Python script in Archicad for the redundant views in project map

Tags: python, archicad

I am exploring the Archicad API where I want to check if I get the redundant views in Project map. So, can anyone just help me out with the same if have any experience on it. The basic script type where I can just add my Python script and which Archicad software will accept it.

Tried the given Archicad scripts but it is for specific issues not for all. So, I want to develop my own script for the redundant views in a project map.